# Import конфликт

Tags: java, jvm, импорт, instance

Предположим есть класс `com.fox.Client`. Этот класс есть как и в проекте так и в импортируемой библиотеке. В каком-то классе проекта я импортирую этот класс.

Вопрос, какой класс подгрузится, тот что есть в текущем класпасе или с импортируемой библиотеки, ведь пакет у них идентичный.

Answer (score 2):

Компилятор Java смотрит в директорию src и компилирует все что там есть, следовательно он найдет там нужный импортируемый класс, если класс не найден, то тогда он будет его искать в classpath.

Если на момент компиляции нужный класс еще не откомпилирован, то он будет загружен из classpath.

В общем можно утверждать, что выборка импортируемого класса неопределена.

Comment: Это на этапе компиляции, а как поведёт себя JVM на этапе выполнения? При подгрузке класса она так же будет смотреть? А если будет несколько библиотек с таким же классом?

Comment: При выполнении поиск и загрузка в порядке classpath. Если класс находится в том же jar, то из него.